# block disappeared at the end of the animation - CSS 3

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I want to make a simple effet: slide a div from right to the center of a div (300x300).

I success to do that by using animation:

```css
/* Place your styles here */
*, input, button{
 font-family:"Roboto Slab";
}

.ad{
 width:300px;
 height:250px;
 overflow:hidden; /* elements won’t spill outside of the ad */
 position:relative; /* make it easier to position elements */
 background-color:#efefef;
 color:#3A3A3A;
  text-align: center
}

.h1-background{
 color:white;
 background-color:#003967; /* #4285F4;*/
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
 text-align:center;
  height: 100px;
}

h1#text-1{
 position:relative;
  font-size: 26px;
}

h1#text-2 { 
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;  

  -moz-animation-name: dropHeader;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;      

  -webkit-animation-name: dropHeader;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 5s;

  animation-name: dropHeader;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;  
}

@-moz-keyframes dropHeader {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 200px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes dropHeader {
   from {left: 300px;}
    to {left: 0;}
}
@keyframes dropHeader {
    from {left: 300px;}
    to {
      left: 0px;      
    }   

}

.company-logo
{
  width:80%;
  height: auto
}
button{
 padding:5px 20px; /* give the button some padding */
 font-size:20px; /* expand the font size */
 background-color:  #95c11a; /*#4285F4;*/
 border:none; /* Remove the default border */
 color:white; 
 margin:auto; /* Centers the button */
 margin-top:7px;
 display:block;
 position:relative; /* Position relatively for animation */
 cursor:pointer;
 border-radius:50px; /* Give the button a rounded look */
 cursor:pointer;

 -moz-animation-name: raiseButton;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-duration: .7s;


  -webkit-animation-name: raiseButton;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .7s;


  animation-name: raiseButton;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
  animation-duration: .7s;
 
}
@-moz-keyframes raiseButton {
    0% {
      -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
      opacity :0;
    }
    50%{
     -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
     opacity :0;
    }
    100% {
      -moz-transform: translateY(0);
      opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes raiseButton {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
        opacity :0;
    }
    50%{
     -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
     opacity :0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@keyframes raiseButton {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(100px);
        opacity :0;
    }
    50%{
     transform: translateY(100px);
     opacity :0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity :1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- your ad goes inside here -->
   <div class="ad">
    <img class="company-logo" src="company-logo.png" />
    <div class="h1-background">     
     <h1 id="text-2">test test</h1>
    </div>
    <button id="cta">
    azerty
    </button>
   </div>
```

But I want a 2s delay before the animation stats. If I add animation-delay: 2s;, the text of the div is shown during 2s, after the animation starts and the text disappears, the text slides, but at the end, it disappears again.

How can I do not to have it at the before the animation, but that it stays visible after the animation ?

I tried with opacity, visibility in the animation, but nothing works.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have consistency here

```
@-moz-keyframes dropHeader {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 200px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes dropHeader {
  from {left: 300px;}
  to {left: 0;}
}
```

and If you use:

```
transform: translateY(100px);
```

why you don't use 
    transform: translateX in dropHeader too?

fix that and try again

If you want apply the property values for the time the animation ended use.

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

You can check this codepen if you want
  http://codepen.io/tarod_spj/pen/vKBVaK

I hope that hepl you.

Comment: Hi Roberto, sorry for the consistency. I forgot to clean all the tests I did.  Thanks for the "forwards". That's exactly what I wanted ! :)